# Switching theme with ThemProvider causes the widget to reset its state

Tags: flutter, state, themes, reset, provider

I'm working on a small quiz application, and I would like to add a switch to toggle light/dark mode.

I was following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/HSAa9yi0OMA), but here's the problem:

**When I tap the switch to change the theme, the whole widget gets rebuild** (I've printed the hashes and they're different each time I toggle the switch), **and so its state and variables**. But since in that page I load some resources and update the widget components (for instance, I load the quiz questions from a file, and update some texts saying how many questions there are), those get reset.
The problem is that *I just want the theme to change*, leaving the widget and its variables as they are, but I can't find any solutions/workarounds or explaination on why it happens.

Here's a gif of what happens:
[Debug test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJC2m.gif)

Those are the involved files and classes:

#### main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
      builder: (context, _) {
        final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);

        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'ROquiz',
          themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
          theme: MyThemes.themeLight,
          darkTheme: MyThemes.themeDark,
          home: ViewMenu(),
        );
      });
}
```

#### themes.dart

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.light;

  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleTheme(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyThemes {
  static final themeLight = ThemeData(
    colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    //iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue[900]),
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    )))),
  );

  static final themeDark = ThemeData(
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.indigo[700],
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(),
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue))))));
}
```

#### change_theme_button_widget.dart

```
class ChangeThemeButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);

    return Switch.adaptive(
        value: themeProvider.isDarkMode,
        onChanged: (value) {
          final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);

          provider.toggleTheme(value);
        });
  }
}
```

#### ViewMenu.dart

```
class ViewMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  // [...]
}

class ViewMenuState extends State<ViewMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    
    return Scaffold(
      // [...]
      ChangeThemeButtonWidget(),
      // [...]
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and I'm posting it there cause I think it might be useful to someone else.

What I did wrong is that I was using *the widget* to store some state (and access it with `widget.`). So each time I used the switch to change the theme, the widget would get rebuilt, aswell as its internal variables (i.e. the state). Instead, by **moving each variable to the state class, it works just fine, and the state remains unchanged when switching.**

#### class ViewMenu

```
class ViewMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  ViewMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  // I hasome state there

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ViewMenuState();
}
```

#### class ViewMenuState

```
class ViewMenuState extends State<ViewMenu> {

  // The state should be all there for the theme changer to work properly

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    
    return Scaffold(
      // [...]
      ChangeThemeButtonWidget(),
      // [...]
    );
  }
}
```

It appears that with ThemeProvider, flutter rebuilds the widget but not its state, so in order for it to work, with a StatefulWidget, you have to store everything in the class that extends State.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the solution for this is store the progress on your local storage.
you can use shared preferences
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences